# Prove that $\bigcap \{A_i : i \in \{ \}\} = U$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book *General Topology*, by Lipschutz, there is a specific note that $\bigcap \{A_i : i \in \{ \}\} = U$, where ${A_i}$ is an arbitrary indexed family of sets and $U$ \is the universal class. However, I find difficulty in proving it. Help please.

Comment: What is $U$? What are the $A_i$?

Comment: U is the universal set and A_i is indexed sets

Answer (score 1):

(I’ll write $\varnothing$ instead of $\{\}$.) By definition

$$\bigcap_{i\in\varnothing}A_i=\{x\in U:x\in A_i\text{ for all }i\in\varnothing\}\;.$$

What does it take to show that a particular $x$ is **not** in this set? If $x\notin U$, then certainly

$$x\notin\{x\in U:x\in A_i\text{ for all }i\in\varnothing\}\;,$$

so at least we know that $\bigcap_{i\in\varnothing}A_i\subseteq U$. What about some $x$ that is in $U$? The only way to show that it’s not in $\{x\in U:x\in A_i\text{ for all }i\in\varnothing\}$ is to find an $i\in\varnothing$ such that $x\notin A_i$. Is that possible? Is it even possible to find an $i\in\varnothing$, never mind whether $x$ is in that $A_i$ or not?